# Copy files in folders in alphabetical order in BASH Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm attempting to copy a series of files and folders using BASH in Ubuntu.  It is important for the files to be copied in alphabetical order because they are going in a digital picture frame that reads the files in the order in which they were added to the flash drive.  From what I've discovered, Nautilus copies them based on the inode number, so they end up out of order on the picture frame.

From the searching I've done, I've come up with the following command:

```
for i in "$(find * -type f -print0 | sort)"; do cp -v "$i" "/media/PicFrame/$i"; done
```

which results in an error that the file name is too long.  It appears that BASH is trying to make a file with every file name separated by "\n".  I've tried removing some of the quotes, but that results in several "cannot stat" errors when trying to copy pieces of files names (since many have spaces in them).

Any ideas on how to make this work?  I'm open to other methods, but I'd really like this to be a single command/script that I can run each month when I change out the pictures.  (I have been doing this in Windows, but am trying to do everything in Ubuntu now.  I've been back and forth for about two years now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `read` in a `while` loop instead.

```
find ... | while read file
do
  cp ..."$file"...
done
```

You may want to consider using `rsync` instead though.

Comment: Sweet, rsync looks like exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, for the former to work he'll have to remove the `-print0` from the `find`

Comment: @mVChr: Or add `--files0-from=-` to `sort` if his version supports it (it's likely that it does since he's using Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

As Ignacio has mentioned, you should use a `while read` loop if you're using `find`.

If you don't need recursion (your files are all in one directory level), you can use a `for` loop with globbing. When using this technique, you don't need to use `sort` since the glob is guaranteed to be expanded in lexicographical order for your locale (in other words "sorted").

```
for file in *
do
    cp "$file" dest
done
```

You should note that part of the problem with the script in your question is that you're using `print0` to pipe the output of `find` into `sort`. In order to have that work, you will need to the appropriate option to `sort` if your version has it.

```
find ... -print0 | sort --files0-from=-
```